# Website in mobile landscape, keyboard layout issues

Tags: android, css, orientation

In a website I'm designing, I'm using the following layout to ask for a user's phone number:

[image]

This is fine on portrait orientation. However, on landscape orientation, at least with Android, I'm getting this:

[image]

I can save some space by maybe hiding the navigation bar, tweaking some pixels here and there, but still, this appears to be a sub-optimal user experience. I looked into orientation locking, but this works only for full-screen applications, or websites that have been added to the homescreen. Is there another way to prevent the keyboard from taking up more than 80% of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is normal , the main issue is your mobile have a small screen